# Group by value based on column

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to group the sum of values by stores. Here is the Python script:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\JaneWilson\\Documents\\Test\\Left 
File.csv", "r")

print(data.groupby('store').value.sum())
```

it keeps giving me a KeyError: 'store'.

My columns in the csv file have no spaces or whitepspaces.

Comment: That would imply that you don't have that column in `data`.  What does `df.columns` show?  How about `'store' in df.columns`?

Comment: What is the output of `df.columns`? The error means there isn't a column named `store`.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in read_csv is the seperator, so it will seperate store into to columns: 'sto' and 'e'.
This is the reason there is no key 'store', remove the second argument of read_csv and it should work.